# What is the bytes data param in safeTransferFrom?

Tags: solidity, erc-721

In ERC721 and ERC1155, `safeTransferFrom` has `bytes data` parameter.

```
function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) public;
```

how do I send data (is it in hex format?) and what does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering you are interfacing with an existing contract (i.e. calling it).

You can send any data you want, such as a string converted to bytes. Here is just one example I have lying around on how to wrangle strings and bytes https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract/blob/master/contracts/SuNFT.sol#L221-L239

The reason why you would do this is application-specific. In other words, only send data if the specific ERC-721 contract you are sending to *tells* you to, and follow any prescriptions they give you. The myriad ways that applications could describe how you would use these bytes could not be predicted in 2018 (when ERC-721 finalized) and no value existed in cataloging and standardizing these use cases ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when looking at the [openzeppelin's solution](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721BasicToken.sol#L200) 
, `data` param is passed to the `onERC721Received` which does nothing essentially. All the values passed to that function technically do nothing but it only gets the function signature. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: That is correct. OpenZeppelin and 0xcert maintain reference implementations. That means they should have the minimal acceptable feature set. The minimal acceptable feature for `onERC721Received` is to do nothing and this is how they have implemented it.